# Use Django Backward Relation to Show Only n Objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am currently using Django backward relationships to determine what `organizations` the logged in user belongs to, and then display `leads` that belong to this organization. This is how I am accomplishing this in my html template:

```
{% for organization in organization %}
    <h3>{{ organization.name }}</h3>

    {% for lead in organization.lead_set.all %}
        {{ lead.first_name }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

This however displays all the leads that belong to an organization, is there anyway I can limit the number of leads that show up to say the last 5? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice), so:

```
{% for lead in organization.lead_set.all|slice:"5" %}
```